# How to read contents of MemoryStream, fed by a cryptostream

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I am working on some AES encryption in C#. I have a similar decryption method which functions flawlessly, however, no matter what I try I cannot read the encrypted contents of the MemoryStream

I have tried a few different ways of reading,

```
ms.Position = 0;
return new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd()
OR
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs)) {
return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
OR
byte[] enc = ms.ToArray();
string ret=null;
foreach (byte b in enc) {
ret += b.ToString();
}
```

Here's the snippet from the code.

```
 using (AesManaged aesMan = new AesManaged()) {
                if (keystr.Length == aesSize/8)
                {
                    //Its a valid key
                    aesMan.KeySize = aesSize;
                    aesMan.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystr);
                    aesMan.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivstr);

                    ICryptoTransform encryptor aesMan.CreateEncryptor(aesMan.Key, aesMan.IV);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                            {
                                sw.Write(inpstr);
                                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms)) {
                                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                                }


                            }
                        }
```

I get various errors, such as the stream is not readable, or that it cannot read a closed stream, as well as a blank string being returned. 
Has anyone got any ideas? I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those stream functions like `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, etc., close the underlying stream when you `Dispose()` them.  Try not disposing them until you are done, or using the constructors that allow you to chose not to close the underlying stream.  In rare cases, I've had to implement a dummy wrapper around a stream to prevent closing the underlying stream

Comment: Okay, so I would add another ```using memorysteam ms = new memorystream()``` around the other 3, and then read that one out?

Comment: Hey Tim, this doesn't give me an error, however, it simply returns a blank string. ```MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs);
                        sw.Write(inpstr);
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                        return sr.ReadToEnd()```

Comment: Move your memory stream back to the beginning after writing it and before reading it: `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: Same problem mate, just returning a blank string. It seems like there's an issue between the `StreamWriter`, `CryptoStream` and `MemoryStream`. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working by using a dummy wrapper and converting it to an array, thanks for your help